# Powershell WPF style template for disabled ListBox

Tags: wpf, powershell, templates, listbox

I have a powershell script which at some point creates a WPF form for some basic input from the user.
I have a `ListBox` with `CheckBoxes` where user selects necessary options, but it is disabled by default, and user needs to do some actions before it enables. As you can see from below XAML, the overall design is dark, so default disabled styling for `ListBox` looks pretty ugly. How do I need to change below XAML, so that when disabled, I can control at least the background? I know that I need to create a style template and add trigger that switches styles when `ListBox` is disabled, but I tried several approaches found online and none of them work.

Here's the XAML I'm using

```
<Window x:Name="MyLittleFormMainWindow" x:Class="MyLittleForm.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyLittleForm"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="My Little Form" Height="450" Width="800" FontFamily="OCRB" FontSize="14" Opacity="0.8" Background="#33000000" Foreground="Lime" BorderBrush="#05000000" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" BorderThickness="0" ResizeMode="NoResize">


    <Grid Margin="0,10,4,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="173*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="18*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="61*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



        <Button x:Name="buttonGetFiles" Content="Press to enable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="48" Background="#F2323232" Foreground="#FFFDA100" FontSize="18" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="checkBoxList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsListProperty}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Background="#F2323232" Foreground="#FFFDA100" Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False" >

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="2">

                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" BorderBrush="#FF000A64" Background="Lime" Foreground="Lime" Content="{Binding Content}" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
        <Label x:Name="textLabel" Content="My Little Form" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="OCR A Extended" FontSize="42" Foreground="Lime" Height="48" />



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: *I tried several approaches*. Can you mention at least one and post what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a style for `ItemsPanelTemplate` of the `ListBox` only.

Try this one as an example:

```
    <Grid Margin="0,10,4,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="173*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="18*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="61*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <Button x:Name="buttonGetFiles" Content="Press to enable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="48" Background="#F2323232" Foreground="#FFFDA100" FontSize="18" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="checkBoxList" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Margin="10,10,10,10" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="200" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsListProperty}" 
             SelectionMode="Multiple" 
             Foreground="#FFFDA100" 
             Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row="1" 
             IsEnabled="False" >
        <ListBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F2323232"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F2323232"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Style>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel >
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F2323232"></Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#AA323232"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                </StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="2">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" BorderBrush="#FF000A64" Background="Lime" Foreground="Lime" Content="{Binding Content}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
    <Label x:Name="textLabel" Content="My Little Form" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="OCR A Extended" FontSize="42" Foreground="Lime" Height="48" />



</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok, looks like it's working, although I do not understand how. Could you please elaborate what exactly is being done with this XAML? I also see three different places where background color is specified - what are those?

Comment: Ok, looks like `<ListBox.Style>` is completely unnecessary, and it is `<LitsBox.ItemsPanel/>`'s background that we see. There is style defined for it with first color being when it's in normal state, the trigger looks up the tree to `ListBox` and it's property `IsEnabled`, when it's 'false', it triggers to the second color. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I take this back, `<ListBox.Style>` might be necessary since its background is still visible as 1px frame around `<Items.Panel>`

Comment: @miguello: to get why I need to place background color into different places I suggest you to try change all of them one by one to see where they took part in the style. For a final solution the best choice is to move the color you choosed for Background into a separated Style then link it here as a Static Resource.